# How do I pass the users model as the ForeignKey value while saving a ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

The models file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Book(models.Model):
    rel_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Posted By")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Title")
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description")
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Price")
    state = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="State")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="City")
    neighbourhood = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Neighbourhood")
    phone = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Phone Number")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + f" ({self.rel_user.username})"
```

The forms file:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from Books.models import Book


class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'price', 'state', 'city', 'neighbourhood', 'phone']
```

The views file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from Books.forms import BookForm
from django.contrib import messages


def sell(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = BookForm()
    else:
        form = BookForm(request.POST, )
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success("Successfully added!")
            return redirect('sell')
        else:
            messages.error("Please fill in all the fields.")
    return render(request, 'Books/sell.html', {"form": form})
```

Every time a user submits the form, I want the ForeignKey's value to be filled with that users model. How do I do this?
So suppose user "John" has filled the form. When he clicks submit, the details he enters + his user model should go into the database for that entry.

Comment: You mean, the **`rel_user`** should get assigned with ***logged-in user***?

Comment: Yes, the rel_user should get assigned with the logged-in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the user to the `instance` of the `form`:

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from Books.forms import BookForm
from django.contrib import messages

```
def sell(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = BookForm()
    else:
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        form.instance.rel_user = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success('Successfully added!')
            return redirect('sell')
        else:
            messages.error('Please fill in all the fields.')
    return render(request, 'Books/sell.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def sell(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.rel_user = request.user
            instance.save()
            messages.success("Successfully added!")
            return redirect('sell')
        else:
            messages.error("Please fill in all the fields.")
    else:
         form = BookForm()
    return render(request, 'Books/sell.html', {"form": form}
```

request.user can be assigned to rel_user as above